# Changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/’: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, chown

I have just made a huge mistake by changing the owner of my `/usr/bin` from `root` to an ordinary `user`. Whenever i try to execute `$sudo chown root /usr/bin` this gives me :

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/’: Operation not permitted
```

I have read many topics talking about this issue, which most of them give a solution in case you have already a backup image of your OS. Unfortunately I don't have any backup. Is there any solution then other than reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: Did you change ownership recursively? If so you have most likely changed the owner of the sudo binary, so it can't gain root privileges any more.

In that case you need to use plain "su" to become root and then change it back, this only works if the root account has a password (that you know). Otherwise you need to reboot the system into a root shell, e.g. by editing the boot command line to include "init=/bin/sh" and change it back from that shell.

Comment: Yes that's the big problem, i have executed a chown -R on /usr/bin

Comment: See above. I added to the comment after accidentally submitting it by pressing return :)

Comment: Plain "su" lives in /bin so it wouldn't have been affected by your change. If you can get root, "chown -R root /usr/bin" should undo most of the damage done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have actually tried the su trick but it asks me always to give some password that I haven't set the first time while i did install the OS on my machine, what should i do in this case please?

Comment: sudo su, then passwd? If the old pass is random, you might be able to google a solution (mounting the disk rw from grub etc)

Comment: sudo command is not working anymore, all i get is this message "sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't gain root with plain "su" because you don't know the password or none has been set, then you have to reboot into a root shell. When you see the GRUB boot menu, press "e" to edit the kernel command lines, and append "init=/bin/sh" - then it will dump you into a single-user root shell instead of the normal boot process. Here you may have to remount the root file system read/write:

```
# mount / -n -w -o remount
```

Then you need to undo the damage from earlier:

```
# chown -R root /usr/bin
```

Then finally remount the file system read-only, sync and reboot:

```
# mount / -n -r -o remount
# sync
# reboot -f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ThomasH for your detailed solution. I will try it and give you a feed-back.

Comment: The trick with booting into single user root shell is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlA1vmEn3UY It may be helpful if you're having problems getting it to work. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks you so much that helped me a lot,  i really appreciate your help. I could finally fix the problem using also this useful topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682297/getting-message-sudo-must-be-setuid-root-but-sudo-is-already-owned-by-root

Comment: Great, remember to accept the answer if your problem got solved!

Answer (score 16):

Solution:- Get in to Ubuntu Recovery Console
Start your computer and press and hold SHIFT key while booting. It will take you to the grub loader page as shown in image – 1.

[image: Image 1]

Image 1

Select and enter Advanced options for Ubuntu and from there select the kernel named as recovery mode as shown in image – 2.

[image: Image 2]

Image 2

select root – drop to root shell prompt as shown in image – 3

[image: Image 3]

Image 3

Now the file system is read only to Remount to Read Write run below command

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

## mount –all

then need to change the ownership for sudo

```
# chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
```

give permisson for sudo

```
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

it’s done … let’s see by restarting the machine

```
# shutdown -r now
```

You should have your Sudo back by now....

Comment: Really useful! 1+