# Fedora: Changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/’: Operation not permitted

Tags: sudo, fedora, chown

I tried to install VMware Tools on my Fedora but after I copied the tarball into Desktop directory, I cannot use sudo any more. I tried chown to fix it but it didn't work either. I am new to Fedora and I found a similar problem in this link [Changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/’: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102506/changing-ownership-of-usr-bin-operation-not-permitted), however the answer only works for Ubuntu. I wonder how I can fix my problem.

```
[bunny@fedora gawk-5.1.1]$ su
Password: 
su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted

[bunny@fedora /]$ $sudo chown root /usr/bin
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/bin': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What made you decide that changing ownership of `/usr/bin` was the step you needed to take? (Can you show `ls -ld /usr/bin`, please?) How does does `sudo` fail in general for other things? (You note that you can't use it anymore?)

Comment: @mattdm Thank you, yesterday I chose to reinstall my Fedora system because I had to solve this problem quickly. I searched the "su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted" problem online and changing ownership seemed to be the only solution. I am sorry that I forgot to record the result of `ls -ld /usr/bin`.

Comment: It might have been that, but that might have been a red herring. Oh well -- glad it works for you now!