# Issues faced in cordova installation in ubuntu

Tags: android, ios, linux, cordova, ubuntu

using this [ubuntu cordova installation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/)

i enter this on terminal
**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa

### **RESPONSE :**

**sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set**

FAILED to create Helloworld example and install cordova dependencies in ubuntu.

Comment: It sometimes when the permissions of the sudorers file has changed

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/471503/160840) for a quick fix

Comment: erum@erum-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-MT:~$ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/sudo’: Operation not permitted
 @Olu  pls check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682297/getting-message-sudo-must-be-setuid-root-but-sudo-is-already-owned-by-root/19306929#19306929